# Method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::frist does not exist

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Facing issue running this command

```
$data = \App\ReleaseData::whereReleaseId($release->id)->frist();
```

And this is the complete code block.

```
$releases = \App\Release::all();

    $withOutDataReleases = [];
    foreach ($releases as $release){
        $data = \App\ReleaseData::whereReleaseId($release->id)->frist();

        if (!$data){
            array_push($withOutDataReleases, $release);
        }
    }

    return response($withOutDataReleases);
```

Comment: post your ```ReleaseData``` class

Comment: class ReleaseData extends Model
{
   // My model logic in this class
}

Comment: Use first() rather than frist()

Comment: Seems like this is just a typo. I suppose the function should be `first()`. Also, watch out for n+1 problem with your code!

Comment: Okay Thanks buddy.. Error found.. spelling mistake of first();    :)

Comment: @Jerodev how can i improve this query.

Comment: @ShehzadAslam you need to check Eloquent relationship, especially this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your method you have call wrong method the spelling of `first()` is wrong try 
like this

```
App\Flight::where('active', 1)->first();
```

Comment: whereReleaseId($release->id)->first() actually this is same like.. where('release_id', $release->id)->first()

Comment: @ShehzadAslam `frist != first`

Answer (score 0):

```
$releases = \App\Release::all();

    $withOutDataReleases = [];
    foreach ($releases as $release){
        $data = \App\ReleaseData::where('ReleaseId',$release->id)->frist();

        if (!$data){
            array_push($withOutDataReleases, $release);
        }
    }

    return response($withOutDataReleases);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = \App\ReleaseData::whereReleaseId($release->id)->first();
```

`frist` will need to be `first();`